# Unit-tests for Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-test

I'm new to Boost.Spirit and Boost.Test and I would like to know how you verify the correctness of your grammars. Below is a simplified version of how I do it at the moment and I'm pretty sure that there's a better way:

Each test case hase a pair of two strings containing the text to parse and the expected result delimited by semicolons.

The parse functions does the actual parsing and returns a string which should be equal to the expected result.

```
 std::string parse(std::string const & line) {
  std::string name;
  int hours;

  rule<> top_rule = ... ; // rule assignes values to 'name' and 'hours'

  parse_info<> info = parse(line.c_str(), top_rule);

  if(info.full) {
    std::stringstream sstr;
    sstr << name << ";" << hours;

    return sstr.str();
  }

  return "parser failed.";
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( TestSuite )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( TestCase ) {
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(parse("Tom worked for 10 hours."), "Tom;10");
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Comment: I don't, but in what why do you want it "better"?

Comment: I would split this into a question and a possible answer. That way people can vote if they think your solution is really the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, your approach seems fine to me. I would probably group class of tests into function with descriptive names, e.g. TestInvalidGrammar, TestErrorHandling, TestNestedGrammar etc. and have those called from the main.

I am sure you have read documentation but take a look at [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/manual-nullary-test-case.html) if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see how they (the boost spirit authors) test their own parsers: http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/spirit/test/qi/grammar.cpp . For each part of qi you can find a C++ file here: http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/spirit/test/qi/.